# Question on Algebra

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let $P(x)$ be a fourth degree polynomial with coefficient of leading term be $1$ and  $P(1) = P(2) = P(3) = 0$, then find the value of $P(0) + P(4)$ .

Comment: An even worse title would be "Question about mathematics".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Hint:
as the coefficient term is 1
$$P(x)=(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)(x-a)$$, 
then $$P(0)+P(4)=6a+6(4-a)$$.

Comment: I think it's worth noting that $P(0) + P(4) = 6a + 6(4-a) = 24$, independent of $a$.  Right idea, though, so +1.